# call back function for jQuery post

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#country-list').change(function() {
    country = $('#country-list').val();

    $('td').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $.post("/gsm/findtariff/country:"+country+"/",
        function(data){
            $('#incoming').html(data.incoming);
            $('#national').html(data.national);
            $('#callsToUk').html(data.toUk);
            $('#international').html(data.otherInternational);
            $('#sms').html(data.sms);
        }, "json");
        $('td').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

So basically when a country is chosen from my drop down box (#country-list) it should fade out all of the tds in my tariff table, change their values with the returned post data, and then fade them back in again. However with my current code the td's are fading back in before their values have been changed. How can I get the fadeIn() function to only execute once all of the data has been set?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `$('td').fadeIn();` inside your callback function

```
$('td').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $.post("/gsm/findtariff/country:"+country+"/",
        function(data){
            $('#incoming').html(data.incoming);
            $('#national').html(data.national);
            $('#callsToUk').html(data.toUk);
            $('#international').html(data.otherInternational);
            $('#sms').html(data.sms);
            $('td').fadeIn();
        }, "json");
    });
```

Comment: O yeah sorry I should have mentioned I tried doing that but it had no effect the td's still faded in before the values had been set.

Comment: try $('td').fadeIn("slow"); or you can use setTimeout("$('td').fadeIn('slow');",2000); // after 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Move the `fadeIn` call up one line.